# How do I eliminate records in which a specific field is blank in a search?

Tags: search

I'm trying to eliminate records that do not have a mailing address from a list I want to export.  So, how do I do a search to eliminate records in which the city field is blank?

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to CiviCRM SE, Daryl. If you have a current version you could use CiviCRM's new(ish) Search Kit to achieve that. Navigate to **Search menu » Search Kit** or /civicrm/admin/search#/list?tab=custom and create a search like in the screenshot:

[image: Search Kit search for contacts without primary e-mail]

Add all your other search criteria using the search kit's UI and hit search. Then select all found contacts and choose export from the action menu. You could also utilize the "Search Builder" (**Search menu » Search Builder** or /civicrm/contact/search/builder?reset=1) to do so but i would recommend the search kit as the search builder may soon be deprecated / replaced by the search kit.